# Laravel Relationships has/dosentHave not working but with show results

Tags: php, laravel, model, foreign-keys, relationship

I have a Campaign with 3 comments,

I have a working relationship because `$campaign = Campaign::first(); $campaign->comments` returns the 3 comments.

The problem:

```
Campaign::has('comments')->get();
```

returns nothing, when it should return the campaign;

```
Campaign::doesntHave('comments');
```

returns the campaign, when it should return nothing

And most wierd of all:

```
Campaign::doesntHave('comments')->with('comments')->get();
```

returns the campaign, when it should return nothing and it returns it with the variable comments with all 3 of them.

Cant seem to get has and dosentHave working.

Campaign Model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Jenssegers\Mongodb\Eloquent\Model as Eloquent;

class Campaign extends Eloquent {

    protected $connection = 'mongodb';
    protected $collection = 'campaign';

    public function comments(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\CampaignComments', 'campaignsid', 'sidcampaign');
    }
}
```

CampaignComments Model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Jenssegers\Mongodb\Eloquent\Model as Eloquent;

class CampaignComments extends Eloquent {

    protected $connection = 'mongodb';
    protected $collection = 'campaign_comments';

    public function campaign(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Campaign', 'sidcampaign', 'campaignsid');
    }
}
```

Notes: I am using laravel 5.5, mongodb 3.6 and php 7.2

Comment: Could you post your model please? :)

Comment: edited just now.